# Bloquear Alterações DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou criando uma tela de pedido em C# com Windows Forms na qual o usuário preenche os dados do item do pedido e em seguida clica em um botão "Adicionar", que instancia um objeto PedidoItem, adiciona ele a uma lista e em seguida atribui essa lista ao DataSource de um DataGridView. Até aí tudo OK.

Os problemas ocorrem quando o usuário clica na grid. Apesar de estar com a propriedade ReadOnly habilitada, as propriedades AllowUserToAddRows, AllowUserToDeleteRows desabilitadas e a propriedade EditMode setada para EditProgrammatically, quando recebe qualquer clique, a grid estoura a mensagem de erro "O índice -1 não tem um valor.".

Gostaria de poder bloquear alterações nessa grid, permitindo apenas que o usuário selecione linhas para que possa excluí-las através de um botão que será implementado posteriormente.

Talvez seja algo extremamente básico, mas apesar de já ter pesquisado bastante no Google ainda não encontrei nenhuma solução plausível, então qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda!

Grato!

Comment: Independentemente das propriedades alteradas em seu controle DataGrid, você precisa verificar os eventos associados a ele, se criar uma grid nova, notará que o erro não será exibido.

Comment: Você deve estar setando -1 no current row da grid em alguma parte do seu código.

Comment: Ismael, interessantemente funcionou. Mesmo quando colei a mesma grid de volta a partir de um backup do projeto. Fiz vários testes com as propriedades aqui, mas não consegui pegar nada. Enfim, o importante é que funcionou, entender o erro vai ter que ficar para a próxima. Valeu mesmo!